# getting null value in nested bidirectional oneToOne relation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to create two tables person and phonenumber using a model in spring-boot. Person table has an attribute name, age, and person_id where person_id is the primary_key and in the table, phonenumber has an attribute number,person_id where person_id is the primary key and foreign key refers to the person table person_id. and passing the JSON data as a post request to the controller but getting a null value in the phonenumber's person variable of person type.

below are the codes:-
person.java

```
package com.BitGeekTalks.JanShayog.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private long person_id;
    @Column(name ="firstname")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name ="age")
    private long age;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

    public Person(String firstName, long age, PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.age = age;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "person_id=" + person_id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber +
                '}';
    }

    public Person() {
    }

    public long getPerson_id() {
        return person_id;
    }

    public void setPerson_id(long person_id) {
        this.person_id = person_id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public long getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(long age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

phonenumber.java

```
package com.BitGeekTalks.JanShayog.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PhoneNumber")
public class PhoneNumber {
    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "phone_number_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long phoneNumberId;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;


    public Long getPhoneNumberId() {
        return phoneNumberId;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumberId(Long phoneNumberId) {
        this.phoneNumberId = phoneNumberId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PhoneNumber{" +
                "number='" + number + '\'' +
                ", phoneNumberId=" + phoneNumberId +
                ", person=" + person +
                '}';
    }

    public PhoneNumber(String number, Person person) {
        this.number = number;
        this.person = person;
        person.setPhoneNumber(this);
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public PhoneNumber() {
    }


}
```

personservice.java

```
import com.BitGeekTalks.JanShayog.model.Person;
import com.BitGeekTalks.JanShayog.repository.PersonRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PersonService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepo personRepo;
    public Person addPerson(Person person) {
        return personRepo.save(person);
    }
}
```

personrepo.java

```
import com.BitGeekTalks.JanShayog.model.Person;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PersonRepo extends CrudRepository<Person,Integer> {
}
```

personcontroller.java

```
package com.BitGeekTalks.JanShayog.controller;

import com.BitGeekTalks.JanShayog.model.Person;
import com.BitGeekTalks.JanShayog.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;
    @PostMapping("/person")
    public String addPerson(@RequestBody Person person){
        //System.out.println(person);
        Person person1 = personService.addPerson(person);
        return person1.toString();
    }
}
```

json data i am passing

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "phoneNumber": {
    "number": "123-456-7890"
  }
}
```

output i am getting as
`Person{person_id=8, firstName='John', age=30, phoneNumber=PhoneNumber{number='123-456-7890', phoneNumberId=8, person=null}}`

table should be as below

```
person(person_id(pk),name,age)
phonenumber(person_id(pk)(fk refer to person.person_id),number)
```

help me out so that i can learn ahead.

Comment: try to print sql query so you can start searching from that `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE`

Comment: thank you for your reply I have added it to the application.properties but can't understand why I am getting a null value in person in phonenumber entity

Comment: you've set fetch type lazy so until you don't call getPerson(), person not loaded. notice it's better because if you call it, person call getphonenumber and they fall into the loop and you give out of memory exception. for test you can set getPerson in toString() method of phoneNumber